# why do I lose ping to a machine when using port mirroring / monitoring (sniffing)?

Tags: switch, packet-sniffer, 3com

I am using port mirroring / monitoring in my 3COM layer 3 switches to look at network traffic (using wireshark).

Sometimes, I have found that I loose connectivity with the remote monitor machine (the machine receiving the port mirror traffic).    I am unable to ping, or connect to it in any way.

However, sometimes it works (and stays) fine - for example, I have had a monitor running (using wireshark) for over 24 hours with no issue.

When it stops pinging, the only way I have found to bring it back is to shut off the monitor port in the switch.   When I do this, it comes right back up - pings start right away to the machine.   Note, by the way that it looks like the monitor machine itself is fine - at least in terms of capturing traffic.   It appears to be capturing traffic the whole time, even when I cant ping it.

Any idea why this happens, or how I might be able to prevent it?

I do not think it is overloaded, as I have experimented with monitoring only one, low volume port and it still happens.

Comment: Does your capture host have one or two interfaces in it? (eg: are you trying to manage the host using the same interface receiving the port-mirror traffic?)

Comment: Only 1.  Would the behavior I describe be considered normal?    So in that case you use a second adapter?

Comment: Best practice generally indicates the use of a dedicated unconfigured port for the capture of mirrored traffic.. and prevents any risk of your administrative interface becoming overloaded in any way.